How can I get code coverage for flutter runtime?
For all research I did for past days, it says flutter can only collect coverage data after running
flutter test --coverage

But what I need is a tool could collect coverage data while app running on mobile device, like running jacoco when jvm, so that I can collect coverage data at any time I want, of course , during dev mode, then I upload the file to my server from the device, and generate coverage report.
Many thanks for advices, may I have some suggestions?
